# What is the equivalence relation given the equivalence classes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $A \subset X$ a subset.  What equivalence relation on $X$ would give rise to the equivalence classes $A$ and $\{x\}$ for $x \in X \setminus A$.  I'm unsure how to formulate the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ if ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if...

$x=y$, or, $x$ and $y$ are in $A$.

It could be clarified that you mean $A$ along with *all* of the singleton subsets of $X\setminus A$ (as opposed to choosing one particular $x$).  For example, you might add a word: "equivalence classes $A$ and *all* $\{x\}$ for $x\in X\setminus A$."